# Matching a string (any order) to strings in an array of a huge size

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, string-matching

```
def Get_Word_List(File_=[]):
    with open("Words.txt") as File: #File of 250k+ words separated via new line 
        for Line in File:
            File_.append(Line.replace("\n",""))
    return File_

def Get_Input(Str=str):
    Str = raw_input("Input 7 letters: ")
    while len(Str) != 7:
        Str = raw_input("Input 7 letter: ")
    return Str.upper()

def Find_Words():
    Letters = Get_Input()
    List = Get_Word_List() #An Array of strings, all in uppercase
    for Word in List:
        pass
```

I am trying to match a string in any order (Max length 7), for example "ZZAFIEA" could give "FIZZ" or "FEZ" to a word or multiple words in an array of size 250k+ and i can't find away to do it, i've tried all sorts, appreciate any bit of help

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: What format is the "array" in? Is it a string? A list?

Comment: Its an Array of strings, sorry if unclear

Comment: @BrandonMorgan, ooh, so you have `['BLAH', 'FIXX', 'FEZ', 'FOO']`, and you want to find the words that you could build with `'ZZAFIEA'`? You should really include sample input/output; it makes things easier :).

Comment: Not very efficient, but you can try to replace `pass` with `if "".join(sorted(word)) in "".join(sorted(letters)): print letters, word`

Comment: Thank you alfasin, that works well enough for my liking

Comment: @alfasin, `'FEZ'` is not in `'AAEFIZZ'`.

Comment: @Cyphase you're right (though you probably meant to say that `'EFZ'` is not in ...) ;)

Comment: @alfasin, no, I meant `'FEZ'`; what do you mean?

Comment: @Cyphase both are sorted alphabetically (since I used `sorted`)

Comment: Oh, whoops. Yea, that :D.

Comment: Using that method i get this as an output
`'Input 7 letters: AAEIFZZ
['AA', 'AE', 'EA', 'EF', 'FAE', 'FE', 'FIE', 'FIZ', 'FIZZ', 'IF', 'ZIZ']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty good solution:

```
from collections import Counter


def counter_is_subset(x, y):
    # If subtracting y from x doesn't return an empty Counter,
    # x is NOT a subset of y.
    return not (x - y)


def find_buildable_words(words, letters):
    letters = Counter(letters)

    for word in words:
        if counter_is_subset(Counter(word), letters):
            yield word


words = ['BLAH', 'FIZZ', 'FEZ', 'FOO', 'FAZE', 'ZEE']
letters = 'ZZAFIEA'

buildable_words = find_buildable_words(words, letters)

for word in buildable_words:
    print(word)
```

On my computer, this runs in ~1.2 seconds with a 250,000 word list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), write a predicate that confirms if a word from the list is contained in your string, then run `ifilter` with your predicate on that list.

Demo:

```
from itertools import ifilter
compare_against = "ABEFGZ"
lst = ['EFZ', 'ZIP', 'AGA', 'ABM']

def pred(word):
    for char in word:
        if char not in compare_against:
            return False
    return True

x = ifilter(pred, lst)

for y in x:
    print y
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
EFZ
AGA
```

**Disclaimer**

This example does not handle well duplicate characters, meaning, by definition you may decide if `AGA` should return or not (The character 'A' appears only once in `compare_against`). If you decide that AGA is not a valid output, the `pred` function should be modified to accommodate that restriction.

Comment: This is wrong; `'AGA'` is not a valid result because there's only 1 `'A'` in ''ABEFGZ'`.

Comment: @Cyphase Did you read the disclaimer ? I put `AGA` there on purpose  :)

Comment: The disclaimer wasn't there when I commented :).

Comment: @Cyphase nice usage of `Counter`!